# how to paint over wrong paint

Tags: painting, paint, paint-removal

I have damaged the paint on my door a little and decided to repaint:

[image]

I ended up painting with the wrong paint:

[image]

How do I fix that? Can I simply go buy white paint with a primer in it and repaint over the creme? Will it show?

Thanks for you kind help in advance.

By the way, if you're interested to know how I ended up painting with the wrong paint... long story short, on the can that I had from the original paint job it said "Ultra pure white...". But on the top, on the sticker it said "creme". I didn't know you're supposed to look on the damn sticker and not on the can!!!!

[[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could chip a small piece and take it to the paint shop like Sherwin and ask them to do a match for you.

Comment: How big does the paint piece need to be? I have a few tiny pieces and one piece that is about 1cm by 0.5 cm. Is that enough?

Comment: They usually need a chip and they'll try to analyze it just call the store ahead of time to see if they can do a match.

Answer (score 1):

The only hard part will be matching the existing color. You can't just go to the store and ask for "white" - there are  different shades of white. Get a few swatches from the store, take them home and see which one is the closest. If you can't get an exact match, then get some other color and paint the whole door at once.

Comment: what if I say "white, satin, Behr"? Are there a lot of those?

Comment: There are hundreds of whites. I'd keep looking for the right paint can.  If in doubt, paint an index card out of every can, we call that a "drift card".  It's no big deal making drift cards for every can of paint you own, since it's easy to wash out the brush with soap and water.

Comment: I don't have the paint can anymore :(